# Angular button (onClick) event not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button that should call a function that logs the user out. For some reason, the event is not working at all. Here is the code:
TS File:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.sass']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: '',
      password: ''
    })
  }

  submit(){
    this.auth.tryLogin(this.form.getRawValue())
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

  public logout(){
    console.log("logout")
    this.auth.tryLogout()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

  // public testJWT(){
  //   alert("asd")
  //   this.auth.testAuth()
  //   .subscribe(res => {
  //     console.log(res)
  //   })
  // }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
    <h1>Anmelden</h1>
    <input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Addresse" required> 
    <br>
    <input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Passwort" required>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Anmelden</button>
</form>

<button (onClick)='logout()'>log out</button>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I tried using this.logout(), I tried type="button" in the html, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be `click` and not `onClick`.

```
<button (click)='logout()'>log out</button>
```

Syntax reference:

[image: syntax]

You can refer to the official wiki https://angular.io/guide/event-binding for more info

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that when I read the docs

Comment: With the latest version of Material, it has added pointer-events rule and sets it to None. So we have to override, to allow the click events. In html like "class=allow-pointer-events" and inside style sheet .allow-pointer-events { pointer-events: all; }

Answer (score 2):

The event is "click". you are using `onClick` which is incorrect.
Please change `onclick` to `click` and check.

`<button (click)='logout()'>log out </button>`

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events

Comment: thank you, I totally missed that. I looked at the docs but apparenlty I didnt read the code properly.